# Использование значений из CoreData

Tags: swift, coredata

Здравствуйте. В CoreData в атрибуте settings хранится float-значение. Как его испольовать для расчета? Вот код для расчета:

```
///tMoney.settings это атрибут в сущности

    let mFWork = Float(((diffHour * 60 + diffMinute - breek) * tMoney.settings/60) - (((diffHour * 60 + diffMinute - breek) * tMoney.settings/60) * 13 / 100))
```

XCode ругается: Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вкратце, xcode не справляется с индексированием этой строки. В ней очень много математических операций, и фактически для каждой ему надо проверить потенциальные overloads.

Предложу вам переписать все это дело, например вот так:

```
let time = Float(diffHour * 60 + diffMinute - breek)
let cash = Float(time  * tMoney.settings/60)
let mFWork = Float(cash - cash * 0.13)
```

Comment: Теперь ругается на let temp. Точно также.

Comment: дробите дальше. сейчас ответ исправлю

Comment: Спасибо. Работает:).